# DependencyProperty to ViewModel

Tags: wpf, wpf-4.0

I have two DependencyProperties TBLocation & TBBroadcastLocation in MyUserControl.
For TBLocation I get information from another element called MyTextBox.
When TBLocation gets set, I set TBBroadcastLocation  with TBLocation's Point information.
And now I would like to make TBBroadcastLocation data available to MyViewModel so that it has TBLocation's data indirectly available to it.

How could I do that or do we have a better approach?

Comment: What does 'For DP2 I would like to pass it to another ViewModel' mean? Please think carefully before you ask questions... have you provided enough information for people to help? Is your question clear? Will people from other countries understand what you're after?

Comment: you want to set two different properties from two different view models?

Comment: Can you illustrate your question with some code? though your question seems a bit unfeasible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm still not sure that I understand... are you simply asking 'How can I bind a property of a `UserControl` to a property of a view model', because there are plenty of examples of that all over the internet... if that's *not* what you're after, you *may* need to be more specific.

Comment: Could you have a look at the new description? Thank you.

Comment: Just so that you know... when I asked for more information, I was *not* asking to see names... names are irrelevant. The 'types' of your properties is more important. Some XAML to give us some context is more important... etc.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me as if you are asking 'How can I bind a property of a `UserControl` to a property of a view model'. You *really* should read the basics of data binding *before* asking these questions here. For future reference, please read the [Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) page at MSDN.

Given that you *still* have not provided enough information, I will assume that your property is of type `string`. In this case, your view model will need a standard property of type `string` to bind to your `DependencyProperty`... this property *must* implement the [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface:

```
private string viewModelProperty = string.Empty;

public string ViewModelProperty
{
    get { return viewModelProperty; }
    set { viewModelProperty = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("ViewModelProperty"); } }
}
```

Make sure that the `DataContext` of the `Window` that has your `UserControl` in it is set to an instance of the view model class:

In the `MainWindow` constructor:

```
DataContext = new ViewModelClass();
```

Or in XAML:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:ViewModelClass}">
    <Views:yourView />
</DataTemplate>
```

Then you simply bind with a `Two Way` binding:

```
<YourNamespace:MyUserControl 
    TBBroadcastLocation="{Binding ViewModelProperty, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```